# what is the equivalent of manova for pretest postest data for paired groups?

Tags: paired-data, group-differences, manova

how can i test for differences in pretest and posttest of anxiety and aggressive behavior in regards to the experimental group only? noting that i have already conducted a MANOVA and found statistical significant differences between experimental and control groups on the posttest results of both anxiety and aggressive behavior, and now i need to asses the difference of both dependent variables between 2 time measurements (pretest posttest) in the control group.

would a repeated measures MANOVA be correct? if i treat the pretest experimental group and p

Comment: You wrote "now i need to asses the difference of both dependent variables between 2 time measurements (pretest posttest) in the control group."   Why do you need to do this?  What purpose would doing this serve?